# Proxy could not connect to the destination in time

Tags: performance, proxy, server, load, mcafee

I have been having issues with loading pages from the website I created. The strange thing is that after I reload a page (e.g. Ctrl+R) especially if I do it multiple times in a row, sometimes that page loads flawlessly fast, sometimes it takes 10-20 seconds and sometimes it doesn't load at all, because, based on the Network tab in the Developer panel, some files are 'pending' to load, but never load. I'm then getting a "proxy could not connect to the destination in time" error if the very first index.php doesn't load, or the page loads only partially and I'm getting an error in the Console "could not connect to [filename]'

Few facts to keep in mind:

1. This issue occurs on all browsers I tested (Chrome, Firefox, IE, and Opera)
2. I am not focused on asynchronizing the stylesheets or script files at this point. As a result, my pages are not loaded until all files are loaded, but at this stage of development, this is not a top priority
3. I'm using GoDaddy shared hosting for this website
4. I am accessing the website through a corporate proxy server (I believe they use McAffee Enterprise)
5. If I test the loading speed using external tools (tools.pingdom.com or google developers tool), there appears to be no issue with the loading speed
6. Even under the corporate proxy server, I have never had this issue with any other websites

My questions is whether anybody else had this issue and knows how to mitigate it. If it's the proxy, I'm not sure why other sites work just fine. Any thoughts?